# Getting mp3 file length

Tags: c#, mp3, duration, bass

I am currently trying to write an Audio Player in C#. I am using BASS library to deal with playing music but now i have small problem with getting length of the song.

Well i have read BASS doc and found a way:
"All" i need to do is

```
int stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(filepath,....);
int length = Bass.BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(stream, Bass.BASS_ChannelGetLength(stream));
```

And in most of cases i get valid length of song. And here the problem starts. As far as i know the stream creation operation is quite expensive (correct me if i am mistaken) and creating a stream only to get length of the song looks a little silly.

So my question is: Is there any other way to get it without creating steam file (not being so expensive). I will be thinking later about reading id3 tags. Is creating that stream "evil that must be done no matter what" and even if i would try to get it with other library it would do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/):

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
```

Then code like so:

```
string file = "myfile.mp3"
ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file);
double 100nanoseconds;
double.TryParse(so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString(), out 100nanoseconds);
```

There is a [code project that could help you as well](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43208/How-to-get-the-length-duration-of-a-media-File-in)

Comment: Well but is this liblary doing something different then i have wrote in code?

Comment: It should be much less expensive.

Comment: Small point, Media.Duration is in 100nS, not nanoseconds, so its 
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,(int) (nanoseconds/ 10000000));

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787399(v=vs.85).aspx