# C# Find Video and Audio file length

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a simple solo project to find and continuously play songs off of my machine, one after the next. The music is in various formats that I have downloaded.

MP4, MP3, MPEG, AVI, and WAV

Everything works from recursively searching the specified directory for music to playing the file and creating playlists. But I cannot seem to figure out how to find the length of these files in order to determine how long the program should wait before proceeding to another song.

I am building this program using Unity3d on a Windows 8 HP Laptop. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: look this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602652/getting-mp3-file-length

Comment: So it looks like Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell is the library used for this code. I've gone and downloaded the dll for it but where can I install it to be used in my project?

Comment: Propose this be re-opened, as the 'duplicate' question is about a very specific library, BASS, and this is about Unity3D, which has a totally different set of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Audioclip, you can use this :
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip-length.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html

As @Wai Ha Lee suggested, I should add some explanations with the link, so here it is.
You can use the AudioClip.Length and AudioSource.IsPlaying (documentation linked above) in order to get the necessary informations.

Comment: Thanks, but the files I am playing are external to the Unity project. Since they are so many different formats like mp3, mp4, etc. I am playing the songs with Media Player instead of streaming them into Unity.

Answer (score 0):

As stud said, for audio files in Unity, use [AudioClip.Length](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip-length.html). And then for video data, you should use [MovieTexture.Duration](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture-duration.html) class.

Working with media files in C# can sometimes (even in 2015) still be a pain point, so my advice is to utilise libraries like [TagLib](http://taglib.github.io/) where possible. If libraries like TagLib are overkill, then look into their source and take the bits you need.